# How to access the cx/cy coordinates of a circle from svg element on atptour.com

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, svg, xpath

I am working on a data science project for school and I want to get the ball coordinates from a page like this one: https://www.atptour.com/en/stats/second-screen/archive/2021/403/MS001

My goal is to get the serve placement for J.Sinner and H.Hurkacz on both the deuce and add sides, for 1st and 2nd serves. Because of the button menu, my research has led me to use selenium with python for the task, so I can click through the different options. The svg element looks like this.

I have looked all over stackoverflow for an answer and found many ways to get access the circles but none of them seem to work on this website. Thanks for any advice in advance and let me know if you need any other information!

I have tried `driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "circle")` and `driver.find_elements(By.ID, "ball-plots")` to access the circles in addition to a variety of other techniques to try to access the element. But none of these work and I get an error similar to the following

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ball-plots"]"}`

The rest of my code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

year = "2021"
url = "https://www.atptour.com/en/stats/second-screen/archive/" + year + "/403/ms001"
driver.get(url)`
```

Comment: Why scrape? Looks like the data is in: https://www.atptour.com/-/ajax/HawkEyeSecondScreen/False/2021/403/MS001/

Comment: As an observation: a circle has cx and cy attributes. Those are the coords of the center of the circle.  But maybe it's just a typo in the title of your question

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Excuse my ignorance, but what technique is this? Could you elaborate how you accessed this page? Is it the source page? And if so how should I go about downloading it programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: The data comes from that separatly loaded JSON data file; you can ``fetch`` that file yourself;, and process the JSON data points. Hit F12 to open the explorer and learn to analyse files in the Network Tab. If you don't know how; ask a teammember with those skills (that is how we all work in the business)

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath will get all `circle` under `#ball-plot`

```
//*[@id="ball-plots"]/*[local-name()="circle"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this leads to the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: The page is protected against automation tools.